# NodeJS, DiscordJS. Split arguments by {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How can I get this working, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
const a = args; 
const items = a.slice(a.indexOf('{') + 1, a.lastIndexOf('}')).split('}{')

switch(args[0]) {
    case 'status':
        message.channel.send("**Current Status:**");
        con.query("SELECT * FROM games", function(err, result, fields) {
           if(err) throw err;
            Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
                var row = result[key];
                message.channel.send('**' + row.name + '**' + ' - ' + '(' + row.description + ')' + ' - ' + '**' + row.status + '**');
            });
        });
        break;
    case 'add':
        let name = items[1];
        let desc = items[2];
        let status = items[3];
        console.log(items);
        break;
```

I am trying to split the !ADD commands arguments by {} so this system knows that every other string inside of  {} is the next command

```
!add {this is a argument}{another argument}{another argument sitting here}
```

Comment: regexr.com/4eiig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are splitting the message to parse out the initial command (add), but not joining it back together before doing the next split.  I think you want to change the second line to:

`const a = args.slice(1).join(' ');`

That should make the items array `['this is a argument', 'another argument', 'another argument sitting here']`

When you access the items array, make sure you are using the correct indices as well.  In this example there are only 3 items, so valid indexes would be (0, 1, 2).  (In your code you are accessing 3)

Answer (score 0):

A light regexp-using approach could be:

```js
let line="!add {this is a argument}{another argument}{another argument sitting here}"
let [command,argumentlist]=line.match(/!([^\s]+)\s+\{(.*)\}/).splice(1);
let arguments=argumentlist.split("}{");
console.log(command);
console.log(arguments);
```

The `match()` thing strips the `!` from the beginning and the outermost `{}` pair, and then the `split()` is the same as it was in your code.